# Laravel: Limit columns retrieve in an eagerly loaded relationship, with constraints

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When I eagerly load a straightforward Eloquent relationship I can limit the columns retrieved using the following syntax:

```
MyModel::with(myRelation:id,col_2,col_3);
```

When I want to constrain the members of the relationship, I do this:

```
MyModel::with(['myRelation' => function ($query) {
    $query->where([
        ['field_1', 'a_value'],
        ['field_2', 'b_value']
    ]);
}]);
```

But that loads all columns of the related models.  I tried replacing the key `myRelation` with the full syntax, `myRelation:id,col_2,col_3`, but it throws an error which says the relation name is not found.

I also tried adding the following methods to the `$query`:

```
->select('id', 'col_2', 'col_3')
```

or

```
->addSelect('id', 'col_2', 'col_3')
```

or

```
->get('id', 'col_2', 'col_3')
```

None of these were successful.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "None of these were successful."? `->select('id', 'col_2', 'col_3')` should work.

Comment: you need to also add relation_id (foreign key), so new select should be ->select('id','relation_id','col_2','col_3');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so to get this to work, I had to:

- include the foreign_key in the list of selects (thanks, @ankitPatel), and
- pass the parameters to the select statement as an array, as follows:

  ->select(['id','foreign_key','col3','col4'])

Answer (score 1):

One option could be keeping all the columns (except id, col_2, col_3) hidden in your original model `MyRelation` is pointing to.

```
protected $hidden = ['col_4', 'col_5',...];
```

You could also change the relationship definition in your model `MyModel`:

```
public function myRelation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('MyRelation')->select(array('id', 'col_2', 'col_3'));
}
```

But, in general, this should work:

```
MyModel::with(array('myRelation'=>function($query){
        $query->select('id','col_2', 'col_3)
              ->where([
                       ['field_1', 'a_value'],
                       ['field_2', 'b_value']
                ]);
    }))->get();
```

Remember, you have to include the joining key (say `id`) in the select list above.